# How to add progress bar around a button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-progressbar, android-developer-api

I have created a circle button like this :[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2ckB.png . I want to add a progressbar around that button when a command is given. Please show me how can I add the progress bar around the circle button.
This is the button in main_activity:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/button_elevation"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
```

This is the design of the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >
<solid android:color="#f43532"/>
<stroke android:width="0.2dp" android:color="#f43532"  />
<ripple 
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
</shape>
```

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/circular-progress-button) that might help.

Comment: I dont understand how to add this to my application.

Comment: You wouldn't add it to your application per say, but look at how it was accomplished as an example. Is it even close to what you are trying to do? Did you see the example?

Comment: If you download the project there is a source file called CircularProgressButton,java that could be helpful.

Comment: I found another example [here](http://www.geeks.gallery/horizontal-and-circular-progress-bar-in-android/)